# how many employees working in "xyz" location and name them?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, qsqlquery

I want to find how many employees working in "xyz" location and name them, I have 2 tables emp and dept(dno, dname,location),both these queries shows the count but it does not display all the emp names only display the first match name.I want all names to be displayed.

```
//This query gives names of employess in "xyz"location.
SELECT e.emp_name
      FROM emp_mca e 
  JOIN dept_mca d 
 WHERE e.dno = d.d_no 
   AND location = "xyz";

//This query gives number of employees working at "xyz"location.
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM emp_mca e 
    JOIN dept_mca d 
  WHERE e.dno = d.d_no 
    AND location = "xyz";
```

I wish to combine both of these.

Comment: You're asking for two different things. First, construct a separate query for each thing. Then get back to us, and we'll show you how to put them together.

Comment: you can't use an aggregate function like `COUNT()` if you want to show each employee.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional subquery in order to get the total number of employees that work in the specified location:

```
SELECT e.emp_name, t.cnt     
FROM emp_mca e 
JOIN dept_mca d ON e.dno = d.d_no 
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM emp_mca
   JOIN dept_mca d ON dno = d_no 
   WHERE location = "xyz") AS t
WHERE d.location = "xyz";
```